# ODOO - find a value in a table by query and enter the results in a field

Tags: module, odoo, odoo-9

I created a module to simply add new phone numbers for a customer , and automatically (ONCHANGE Functrion) recognize the Tel Center of the phone number from another model and enter the correct telcenter name by searching from database.

so this is my .PY code:

```html
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from openerp import models, fields, api, http


    class Contacts(models.Model):
        _name = 'isp.contacts'

        name = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Owner")
        telnumber = fields.Char(string="Tel Number", onchange='onchange_telnumber')
        telcenter = fields.Char(string="Tel Center", required=True)

        @api.onchange('telnumber')
        def onchange_telnumber(self):
            if self.telnumber:
                for record in self:
                    record.telcenter = (self.env.cr.execute(
                        'SELECT name FROM isp_precode WHERE name LIKE %record%'))


    class Telcenter(models.Model):
        _name = 'isp.telcenter'

        name = fields.Char('Center Name', required=True)
        ostan = fields.Char('Provience', required=True)
        city = fields.Char('City', required=True)
        manager = fields.Char('Manager', required=True)
        tel1 = fields.Char('Tel Number 1', required=True)
        tel2 = fields.Char('Tel Number 2', required=True)
        mdf_manager = fields.Char('MDF Manager', required=True)
        mdf_tel = fields.Char('MDF Tel', required=True)
        net_manager = fields.Char('Net Manager', required=True)
        net_tel = fields.Char('NET TEL NUMBER', required=True)


    class Precode(models.Model):
        _name = 'isp.precode'

        name = fields.Char()
        telcenter = fields.Many2one('isp.telcenter',
                                    ondelete='cascade', string="Tel Center", required=True)


    class Ports(models.Model):
        _name = 'isp.ports'

        name = fields.Char(required=True)
        port = fields.Char(required=True)
        floor = fields.Char(required=True)
        raw = fields.Char(required=True)
        dslam = fields.Char(required=True)
        slot = fields.Char(required=True)
        dslamport = fields.Char(required=True)
        dslamip = fields.Char(required=True)
        mothercompany = fields.Many2one('product.category',
                                        ondelete='cascade', string="Mother Company", required=True)
        telcentername = fields.Many2one('isp.telcenter',
                                        ondelete='cascade', string="Tel Center", required=True)
```

AND This is my XML view:

```html
    And my XML view is :


        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>

            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="contacts_list_action">
                <field name="name">Service Contacts</field>
                <field name="res_model">isp.contacts</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
                <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the Service Contacts</p>
                </field>
            </record>


            <menuitem id="main_service_menu" name="Services Phone"/>

            <menuitem id="service_menu" name="Service Contacts"
                      parent="main_service_menu"/>

            <menuitem id="contacts_menu" name="Contacts" parent="service_menu"
                      action="contacts_list_action"/>



    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="telcenter_list_action">
                <field name="name">Tel Center</field>
                <field name="res_model">isp.telcenter</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
                <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the Tel Center</p>
                </field>
            </record>


            <menuitem id="telcenter_menu" name="Tel Center" parent="service_menu"
                      action="telcenter_list_action"/>


                    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="precode_list_action">
                <field name="name">Pre Code</field>
                <field name="res_model">isp.precode</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
                <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the Pre Code</p>
                </field>
            </record>


            <menuitem id="precode_menu" name="Pre Code" parent="service_menu"
                      action="precode_list_action"/>

                    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="ports_list_action">
                <field name="name">Ports</field>
                <field name="res_model">isp.ports</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
                <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the Ports</p>
                </field>
            </record>


            <menuitem id="ports_menu" name="PORTS" parent="service_menu"
                      action="ports_list_action"/>

        </data>
    </openerp>
```

Comment: What exactly is that this code should do, what do you expect? And what instead is the result you obtain?

Comment: I want to search the value of 'telnumber' field in 'isp_precode' table and return the results in 'telcenter' field.
But i got 'none' ....

Comment: i think i make a big mistake in this part of CODES:

        def onchange_telnumber(self):
            if self.telnumber:
                for record in self:
                    record.telcenter = (self.env.cr.execute(
                        'SELECT name FROM isp_precode WHERE name LIKE %record%'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, into the select %record% is taken as literal, while it should be parametrized.

Second, don't use at all the cursor for a raw query, but use instead the ORM:

```
    @api.onchange('telnumber')
    def onchange_telnumber(self):
        self.telcenter = self.env['isp.telcenter'].search([('name','like',self.telnumber)]).name
```

Comment: Thanks

but it returns just the ID , but i need to return NAME value of telcenter


Would you Please help me for this?

Comment: I edited my answer, I missed to add the obvious *name* field.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH 

DEAR SIR, ALESSANDRO RUFFOLO


You Give me a big gift



THANK YOU....

Comment: one more question:
What if I want to search from name fields of 'isp.telcenter' and return value of a Many2one field instead of name ?

Comment: just use the name of the field instead of name. Remember to select this answer as correct, please.